Isekai manga/comic about a woman who was transported into a game or novel in which she could only walk a few hundred steps a day
I'm looking for an isekai manga that I read years ago.
It's about a woman who was transported into a game or novel (I think it was a game) that limited her movement. She could only walk a few hundred steps a day and would collapse if the steps ran out. It didn't help that the male lead had a humongous mansion she had to walk through, lol!

It was a fantasy, romance setting.
The female lead had red hair (I believe).
The male lead was either a prince or of high nobility (he had white hair).


Maybe retitle this so it doesn't sound like she's weak, and instead she's "magically limited to a few hundred steps"? A.k.a make it not sound like https://www.reddit.com/r/Isekai/comments/xlr6d1/does_anyone_know_of_this_mangamanhwawebtoon_of_a/

Is this The Villainess's Days are Numbered!...?

I've been reborn as Clea Rino, the world's most wicked villainess! Before her death, Clea made a deal with the Demon King to marry her true love, Isaac Detroi. To get my life back, I must fulfill that contract for just six months. Guess I didn't read the fine print, because her body is weak. I lose 1 HP with every step! With time ticking, I'm signing over her family's fortune for Isaac's hand in marriage. It's purely business, so why am I catching feelings? Who knew this villainess had a heart?


A Korean woman is murdered on her way home from work and then finds herself in a void with a Demon King who offers her a deal. She is to be reincarnated in another world as a redheaded countess, Clea Rino, and must spend the next six months happily married to white-haired grand duke whom Clea loves, Isaac Detroi, in order to return to her own world.
However, due to Clea's frail, sickly body, she loses one health point for every step she takes and starts coughing up blood when her health gets too low. She can regain health by resting, but has to be very calculating about the number of steps she takes, taking into account the exact number of steps required to get from one location to another.
You can read the full manhwa at Tapas.

Is this a LitRPG? Is her only stat "HP"? Whoops, just checked Episode 2. So, basically yes on both points. ... Nevermind, there's "body function" 80%. ok
